# Connecting a NAS device directly to an android device via ethernet and sharing the SMB share on the NAS through android's wifi

Tags: wi-fi, lan, cifs, ethernet

currently I don’t have both devices at the same place to test this, but maybe someone uses a similar setup. So I’d like to use an android tv box with a NAS device connected directly to the ethernet port of the android device. So there is no router in between. I can set a fixed ip address on the NAS, I guess the same can be done on the device running android. And android should immediately detect the SMB share on the NAS when connected this way, right?

Currently I have the NAS connected to an old samsung tv this way and it works as a media server for the tv. But I lose internet on the tv, because wifi can’t be used at the same time when the NAS is connected. What would be really cool is if I could use android’s wifi connection while the NAS is connected to ethernet, and if android was able to somehow passthrough the NAS’ SMB share to the rest of the local network devices, so they could also read/write to the NAS.

Any thoughts if something like this could be done? Connecting the NAS to the router doesn’t work for me, because LAN cable doesn’t reach the place where the tv is and wifi is too slow for video.

Comment: Routing network traffic (except from the standard hotspot/tethering options) always require root to my knowledge. But IMHO you should better check for a Wifi bridge that can directly connect to the NAS. Use a cheap Wifi router/bridge like [TL-WR902AC](https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/wifi-router/tl-wr902ac/)

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. Root is not a problem, I think. Additional device in the setup is a bigger problem, because the setup would be used by not too computer savvy people, so more devices means more things that might go wrong in everyday use :)